# Passing variables to powershell from C# : Output file location variables

Tags: c#, powershell

I have recently began using C# to invoke powershell scripts, with some success :)

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://127.0.0.1 
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary 
$spWeb.Lists.Add($args, "", $listTemplate) > $myDirectory
```

---

`$spWeb.Lists.Add` returns a SharePoint GUID.

**Question:**

> I simply wish to pass in the directory/filename in which the GUID will
>   be written. How could that be done?

I have posted on the MSDN forums here: http://goo.gl/5p0oz but have continued my search on stackoverflow due to a seemingly dead end thread.  This post is a cumulative gathering of the information found through MSDN responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `Set-Content cmdlet` instead, like this. You need to pass the $myFile as a string and Set-Content will do the rest for you -

Inside your script i.e. `MyScript.ps1` here, you will have this piece of code -

```
param([string]$parameter, [string]$myFile)
try
{
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://127.0.0.1 
    $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary 
    $guid = $spWeb.Lists.Add($parameter, "", $listTemplate)
    $guid | Set-Content $myFile
}
catch
{
    throw ("Failed. The error was: '{0}'." -f $_ )
}
```

How to Run:
Open Powershell Prompt and type this

`.\MyScript.ps1 "someparam1" "D:\Output.txt"`

**C# Bit -**

```
private PowerShell _ps;
_ps = PowerShell.Create();

var parameter = new List<string>
                                {
                                    parameter,
                                    myFile
                                };

var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyScript.ps1");
_ps.AddScript(sr.ReadToEnd()).AddParameters(parameter);
_ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am unfamiliar with powershell script, so perhaps you can tell me what I am doing wrong:

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://127.0.0.1
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
param([string]$args, [string]$myFile)
try
{
  MyFunction | %{$_ $spWeb.Lists.Add($args, "", $listTemplate)} | Set-Content $myFile
}
catch
{throw ("Failed. The error was: '{0}'." -f $_ )
}
the $spWeb.List.Add part is actually what returns a sharepoint GUID, The error message I get is: Unexpected token 'spWeb' in expression or statement.

Comment: Well, it turns out that comments to comments aren't very format friendly.

Comment: The way you are using the Syntaxes and parameters of Powershell are entirely wrong I can see. `What is _MyFunction_ doing ?` Where is it defined ?  Try running your code line by line. The way you are calling DocumentLibrary function is wrong. Sorry, its just not correct. **The question what you have asked is about redirectoring the output from a function to a file and you want to pass that filename from C#.** _But, I do not see anything like that here ?_ `Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve here ? Then only I will be in a position to help you`

Comment: My apologies for such an incorrect comment. Allow me to back up.

`$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://127.0.0.1 $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
$spWeb.Lists.Add($args, "", $listTemplate) > $myFile
`

Comment: My apologies for such an incorrect comment. Allow me to back up.

`$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://127.0.0.1 $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
$spWeb.Lists.Add($args, "", $listTemplate) > $myDirectory
`
$spWeb.Lists.Add returns a SharePoint GUID.  I simply wish to pass in the directory/filename in which the GUID will be written. In the original post, the way I am passing in the parameters works for $args, but not for $myDirectory.  I am very new to powershell, so  feel free to not respond if this is a waste of time, but thank you for your attempt.

Comment: The three lines above work one by one in powershell, as long as $myDirectory and $args are actual strings.

Comment: I have updated your question with your doubt. So everything should work for you now.

Comment: Thank you for your excessive help.  This experience makes me realize that I should just cut to the chase about what I am trying to accomplish, and not be afraid to just post the code I am trying to use.  Thank you everyone for your help with this, the code works great.